# ASP .NET upload file - HttpPostedFileBase = null

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, file-upload

i'm trying to upload file from a form using ASP MVC 5.

But my `file.ContentLength` is always = 0

```
public ActionResult Test(int? id, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
       //blabla
    }
}
```

and here my form in .cshtml

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "MyController",FormMethod.Post, new { id = Model.Id, enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit">Ajouter</button>
    </div>

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use this :**

```
var count = Request.Files.Count;

if (count > 0) {
   var files = Request.Files[0];
   if(files.ContentLength > 0){
       Your work here e.g : string name = files.FileName ....
   }
}
```

**Snapshot :**

[image: Working example]

Comment: Thank you, my Request have a contentLength>0 (Request.File[0]), 
butmy var file = Request.Files[0] have a contentLength=0

Comment: Oh it finally work, my contentLength automatically going 0 in my debug but my insert in DB looks good. thank you !

Comment: Finally you got solution , happy for that.